# Как реализовать "GROUP_CONCAT" из MySQL в Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Есть таблица "new_":

| g_id | bg_id | gs_width | gs_height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1179 | 284 | 1 | 0.499941 |
| 1180 | 284 | 0.467223 | 0.958212 |
| 1181 | 285 | 1 | 0.499941 |
| 1182 | 285 | 0.467223 | 0.958212 |
| 1187 | 288 | 1 | 0.499941 |
| 1188 | 288 | 0.467223 | 0.958212 |
| 1193 | 291 | 1 | 0.499941 |
| 1194 | 291 | 0.467223 | 0.958212 |
| 1195 | 292 | 1 | 0.499941 |
| 1196 | 292 | 0.467223 | 0.958212 |

Делаю к ней запрос через SQL:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(new_.g_id) as 'g_id',
    new_.bg_id as 'bg_id',
    GROUP_CONCAT(new_.gs_height) as 'gs_height',
    GROUP_CONCAT(new_.gs_width) as 'gs_width'
FROM
    new_
GROUP BY
    new_.bg_id;
```

Дает такой результат:

| g_id | bg_id | gs_height | gs_width |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "1179,1180" | 284 | "0.499941,0.958212" | "1,0.467223" |
| "1181,1182" | 285 | "0.499941,0.958212" | "1,0.467223" |
| "1187,1188" | 288 | "0.499941,0.958212" | "1,0.467223" |
| "1194,1193" | 291 | "0.958212,0.499941" | "0.467223,1" |
| "1195,1196" | 292 | "0.499941,0.958212" | "1,0.467223" |

Пытаюсь получить такой же результат через DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data_lst = [
 [1179, 284, 1.0, 0.499941],
 [1180, 284, 0.467223, 0.958212],
 [1181, 285, 1.0, 0.499941],
 [1182, 285, 0.467223, 0.958212],
 [1187, 288, 1.0, 0.499941],
 [1188, 288, 0.467223, 0.958212],
 [1193, 291, 1.0, 0.499941],
 [1194, 291, 0.467223, 0.958212],
 [1195, 292, 1.0, 0.499941],
 [1196, 292, 0.467223, 0.958212]
]
df_in = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[str(j) for j in i] for i in data_lst]),
                           columns=['g_id', 'bg_id', 'gs_width', 'gs_height'])
df_out = df_in.groupby(['g_id', 'gs_width', 'gs_height'], as_index=False).agg({'bg_id': ' '.join})
print(df_out)
```

Но получаю следующее:

```
   g_id  gs_width gs_height bg_id
0  1179       1.0  0.499941   284
1  1180  0.467223  0.958212   284
2  1181       1.0  0.499941   285
3  1182  0.467223  0.958212   285
4  1187       1.0  0.499941   288
5  1188  0.467223  0.958212   288
6  1193       1.0  0.499941   291
7  1194  0.467223  0.958212   291
8  1195       1.0  0.499941   292
9  1196  0.467223  0.958212   292
```

А если сделать так:

```
df_groupGr_gID = df_groupGr.groupby(['bg_id', 'gs_width', 'gs_height'], as_index=False).agg({'g_id': ', '.join})
```

То будет такой результат:

```
  bg_id  gs_width gs_height  g_id
0   284  0.467223  0.958212  1180
1   284       1.0  0.499941  1179
2   285  0.467223  0.958212  1182
3   285       1.0  0.499941  1181
4   288  0.467223  0.958212  1188
5   288       1.0  0.499941  1187
6   291  0.467223  0.958212  1194
7   291       1.0  0.499941  1193
8   292  0.467223  0.958212  1196
9   292       1.0  0.499941  1195
```

Что не так я сделал? Как сделать вывод такой же как в SQL-запросе?

UPD:

Если сделать так:

```
df_groupGr_gID = df_groupGr.groupby(['bg_id'], as_index=False).agg({'g_id': ', '.join})
```

То получается похожий уже вариант, но теряется часть данных(нет других полей):

```
  bg_id        g_id
0   284      1179, 1180
1   285      1181, 1182
2   288      1187, 1188
3   291      1193, 1194
4   292      1195, 1196
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю на сколько это правильно, но я решил это таким способом:

```
df_groupGr_gID = df_groupGr.groupby(['bg_id'], as_index=False).agg({i: ', '.join for i in ['g_id', 'gs_width', 'gs_height']})
```